# fsockopen returns empty string

Tags: php, sockets

Iam trying to navigate under a proxy with authentication with fsockopen under a site with ssl certificate but it returns null or empty string if i do a var_dump on `$data` variable.I am running on xampp windows 10. I need instead of the empty string to see the site or a string. I don't get any other errors, no error_log, nothing. What could be the issue?

```
$ip = '37.48.125.203';
$port = 333;
$login = 'user';
$passwd = 'apassword';
$fp = fsockopen($ip,$port); // connect to proxy
$port_site = 80;
$ssl = true;
$url = 'https://www.checkprg.com';
$utl_without_http_s = str_replace('https://', '', $url);
$utl_without_http_s = str_replace('http://', '', $utl_without_http_s);
if ($ssl) {
    $port_site = 443;
    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://'. $utl_without_http_s, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}
$request  = "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "Host: $url\r\n";
$request .= 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.2.1) ';
$request .= "Gecko/20021204\r\n";
$request .= 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,';
$request .= 'text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,video/x-mng,image/png,';
$request .= "image/jpeg,image/gif;q=0.2,text/css,*/*;q=0.1\r\n";
$request .= "Accept-Language: en-us, en;q=0.50\r\n";
$request .= "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress;q=0.9\r\n";
$request .= "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1, utf-8;q=0.66, *;q=0.66\r\n";
$request .= "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n";
$request .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
$request .= "Referer: http://www.bing.com\r\n";
$request .= "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n";
$request .= "Proxy-Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$login:$passwd") ."\r\n\r\n";
fputs($fp, $request);
$data="";
while (!feof($fp)) { 
    $data.=fgets($fp,64000);
}
fclose($fp);
echo $data;
echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Comment: maybe `$data` is empty, or `ob_flush` clear all output bufer.

Comment: @Naumov I commented everything related to outputbuffer (last 3 lines). I should also see a hit on Google Analytics but nothing.

Comment: You socket open success `$fp` exist? sorry for my English.

Comment: @Naumov Added var_dump after fclose and result was `resource(4, Unknown)`

Comment: why after `fclose` need after `fsockopen`

Comment: @Naumov Commented fclose and I get now `resource(4, stream)`

Comment: Commented `$request .= "Proxy-Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$login:$passwd") ."\r\n\r\n";` and now I get 301 error which means moved permantly, that mean the authorization is the issue, but tested this with curl and those are the pass and username, maybe they have not been added properly in the string.

Comment: You can try send request by telnet, I can't help you because I don't have manual for work on your server...

Comment: @Adrian Have you solved your problem? I have a code same above but with google.com url, it returns empty string and I don't know why. Some other sites returned "200 OK".